# How i can use custom domain in google app engine?

Tags: dns, cloud, gcloud

Hi Google Cloud experts,
I want to use my custom domain www.example.com in **App engine** custom domain.I purchase domain from **GoDaddy**.
How can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine indeed supports the use of custom domains. I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application).

On this tutorial, you will find all the information and steps needed for you to use your custom domain with App Engine.

Besides that, you can even use subdomains and [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcard_mappings), in case you want to use a range of domains or a list of domains, that you can redirect them to your application.

In addition, I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation [Secure your custom domains with SSL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), so you can find security information to implement on your application, once you are using your own domain.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have purchased domain through Godaddy, you just need to point your domain to your hosting provider name server.